# Remove the string before a certain word with R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a character vector that I need to clean. Specifically, I want to remove the number that comes before the word "Votes." Note that the number has a comma to separate thousands, so it's easier to treat it as a string.

I know that gsub("*. Votes","", text) will remove everything, but how do I just remove the number? Also, how do I collapse the repeated spaces into just one space?

Thanks for any help you might have!

Example data:

```
text <- "STATE QUESTION NO. 1                       Amendment to Title 15 of the Nevada Revised Statutes Shall Chapter 202 of the Nevada Revised Statutes be amended to prohibit, except in certain circumstances, a person from selling or transferring a firearm to another person unless a federally-licensed dealer first conducts a federal background check on the potential buyer or transferee?                    558,586 Votes"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
text <- "STATE QUESTION NO. 1                       Amendment to Title 15 of the Nevada Revised Statutes Shall Chapter 202 of the Nevada Revised Statutes be amended to prohibit, except in certain circumstances, a person from selling or transferring a firearm to another person unless a federally-licensed dealer first conducts a federal background check on the potential buyer or transferee?                    558,586 Votes"
trimws(gsub("(\\s){2,}|\\d[0-9,]*\\s*(Votes)", "\\1\\2", text))
# => [1] "STATE QUESTION NO. 1 Amendment to Title 15 of the Nevada Revised Statutes Shall Chapter 202 of the Nevada Revised Statutes be amended to prohibit, except in certain circumstances, a person from selling or transferring a firearm to another person unless a federally-licensed dealer first conducts a federal background check on the potential buyer or transferee? Votes"
```

See the [online R demo](http://rextester.com/BIYZ80757) and the [**online regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Dv5KRn/1).

**Details**

- `(\\s){2,}` - matches 2 or more whitespace chars while capturing the last occurrence that will be reinserted using the `\1` placeholder in the replacement pattern
- `|` - or
- `\\d` - a digit
- `[0-9,]*` - 0 or more digits or commas
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(Votes)` - Group 2 (will be restored in the output using the `\2` placeholder): a `Votes` substring.

Note that `trimws` will remove any leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but how would I remove "votes" as well? Just by removing the parenthesis, right?

Comment: Use `gsub("(\\s){2,}|\\d[0-9,]*\\s*Votes", "\\1", text)`

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest** way is with `stringr`:

```
> library(stringr)
> regexp <- "-?[[:digit:]]+\\.*,*[[:digit:]]*\\.*,*[[:digit:]]* Votes+"
> str_extract(text,regexp)
[1] "558,586 Votes"
```

To do the same thing but extract only the number, wrap it in `gsub`:

```
> gsub('\\s+[[:alpha:]]+', '', str_extract(text,regexp))
[1] "558,586"
```

Here's a version that will strip out all numbers before the word "Votes" even if they have commas or periods in it:

```
> gsub('\\s+[[:alpha:]]+', '', unlist(regmatches (text,gregexpr("-?[[:digit:]]+\\.*,*[[:digit:]]*\\.*,*[[:digit:]]* Votes+",text) )) )
[1] "558,586"
```

If you want the label too, then just throw out the `gsub` part:

```
> unlist(regmatches (text,gregexpr("-?[[:digit:]]+\\.*,*[[:digit:]]*\\.*,*[[:digit:]]* Votes+",text) )) 
[1] "558,586 Votes"
```

And if you want to pull out all the numbers:

```
> unlist(regmatches (text,gregexpr("-?[[:digit:]]+\\.*,*[[:digit:]]*\\.*,*[[:digit:]]*",text) ))
[1] "1"       "15"      "202"     "558,586"
```